Using OWASP Scan on Azure Pipelines
I am trying to integrate an OWASP Zap scan on a simple Python application I have on Azure Pipeline (using a Microsoft hosted agent). I have written a script to start the application and run the scan:
- script: |
    # Start your Python application
    chmod -R 777  ./
    python dsvw.py 
    # Wait for the application to start
    sleep 10
    docker run -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory):/zap/wrk -t zaproxy/zap-stable zap-baseline.py -t http://host.docker.internal:65412 -r /zap/wrk/zap_report.html 

  displayName: 'OWASP ZAP Docker Image Pull and start application and scan'
  continueOnError: true

The pipeline will run, however at this step, it will take very long (>50 minutes) then an error will appear

##[error]The hosted runner encountered an error while running your job. (Error Type: Disconnect).

Can I know what I am doing wrong here? Am I running ZAP via the script correctly?

It seemed that the agent job containing this step had run beyond the default time limit of 60 minutes.

How was the script running on a local machine by the way? Did the session stop itself after the scan?

It appears that the problem you are facing is connected to the execution of ZAP in your Azure Pipeline script. try this not tested but make changes. steps:

script: |
Start your Python application (adjust as per your actual startup command)
python dsvw.py &
Wait for the application to start (adjust sleep time as needed)
sleep 30
Run OWASP ZAP scan
docker run -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory):/zap/wrk -t zaproxy/zap-stable 
zap-baseline.py -t http://localhost:65412 -r /zap/wrk/zap_report.html
displayName: 'OWASP ZAP Docker Image Pull and Scan'


Is host.docker.internal actually resolving properly? If you connect to the running image are you able to wget or curl against it?
